# Angular Project gives following error when run yarn start

Tags: angular, typescript, yarnpkg

I am getting following error when run yarn start

```
92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.min.js'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:490:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:391:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:109:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:289:32)
    at Observable._subscribe (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\virtual-fs\host\sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:161:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:42:54)
    at D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:69:49
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:68:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at D:\software2\w2p\w2p-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\scripts-webpack-plugin.js:67:43
```

Comment: did you try `ng sereve` ?

Comment: @davidr , usually I only try yarn start and it worked for me until this.

Comment: Did you run `yarn install`? Something seems to be missing from the `node_modules`.

Comment: @MilanTenk yeah, I ran it and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wiping `node_modules` and a clean `yarn`/`yarn install` before `yarn start`. it's likely you're missing [`quill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill), which you're depending on.

Comment: I re installed Yarn and it worked. Thank you